# ajax call - web services

Tags: ajax, web-services, jquery

I am trying to use web service & ajax call. Already i have deployed my web-service in my virtual machine.

URL:

http://www.lumiin.ch:8080/lumiin-service/lumiin/control/lookup/Priority

Try this URL with Rest client Jar

Key = accept
value = Application/json

```
$.ajax({  
           type: "GET",  
           url: "http://www.lumiin.ch:8080/lumiin-service/lumiin/control/lookup/Priority", 
           dataType: "json",           
           success: function(resp){  
             // we have the response  
             alert("Server said123:\n '" + resp );  
           },  
           error: function(e){  
             alert('Error121212: ' + e);  
           }  
         });
```

How to display the output from my URL using ajax calls. Any help will be appreciated. i am struggling a lot..

Regards
Karthick

Comment: That url does not provide json, only XML. Take a look at this tutorial: http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/jQuery-AJAX-and-XML-P970.html

Comment: Hi sindre After changing the application type from Json to Xml it shows Error 121212 xmlHttp request. Any idea

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your "dataType" in the $.ajax call to "XML"?

[Explanation of jQuery AJAX data types](http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests)

Also change your $.ajax call's error function to:

```
error: function (request, errorText, errorCode) {
            alert(errorText);
        }
```

This should give you  the details of the error being thrown.